# LINQ SQL Query with a range variable and a constant

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, linq

I have a query where I need to use Join/On, but with that, I get this error message: **You must reference at least one range variable on both sides of the 'Equals' operator.**

Here is my simplified query:

```
 Dim Result As String = (From cust In Model.Customer
                             Join comp In Model.Company On cust.Id_Customer Equals 1
                             Select cust.Name, comp.Name)
```

Is there a way I can do the range variable Equals-comparison to a constant?

Comment: Don't you want to join customer to company?

Comment: I think that is trivial when it comes to the actual problem of comparing range variable to a constant? This query is just a quick mock up in which the 3rd line only matters (Join/On).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While pure SQL `JOINS` allow for a join condition which may not reference either table to be joined, LINQ `Join`s require a join condition which does reference both tables. The condition for `On` requires a comparison of columns from both tables to join. For example, a valid query would be:

```
Dim Result As String = (From cust In Model.Customer
                             Join comp In Model.Company On cust.Id_FavoriteCompany Equals comp.Id_Company
                             Where cust.Id_Customer = 1
                             Select cust.Name, comp.Name)
```

If you had the columns Customer.Id_FavoriteCompany and Company.Id_Company.

You need to join on a column in both tables.

More information:

[Visual Basic LINQ Query Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/linq/introduction-to-linq#VisualBasicLINQQueryOperators)